# Retrofit 2 and Spring Boot Authorization doesnt work

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I want to auth with JWT Spring security.

**Retrofit** instance

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MOCK_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
```

Api

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers(
        "Authorization: Basic VGVzdENsaWVudElkOlRlc3RDbGllbnRTZWNyZXQ=",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
)
@POST("oauth/token/")
fun oauthToken(
        @Field("username") username: String = "%2B79251234567",
        @Field("password") password: String = "123",
        @Field("grant_type") grant_type: String = "password"): Flowable<TokenObject>
```

And I get `"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials"`. Log interceptor shows this

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.1.28:8888/oauth/token/
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 56
D/OkHttp: Authorization: Basic VGVzdENsaWVudElkOlRlc3RDbGllbnRTZWNyZXQ=
D/OkHttp: username=%2B79251234567&password=123&grant_type=password
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (56-byte body)
```

---

But if I use **Unirest**

```
            val response = Unirest.post("http://192.168.1.28:8888/oauth/token")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic VGVzdENsaWVudElkOlRlc3RDbGllbnRTZWNyZXQ=")
                    .body("username=%2B79251234567&password=123&grant_type=password")
                    .asJsonAsync(object : Callback<JsonNode> {

                        override fun failed(e: UnirestException) {
                            println("The request has failed ${e.message}")
                        }

                        override fun completed(response: HttpResponse<JsonNode>) {
                            println("completed")
                            println(response.getBody())
                        }

                        override fun cancelled() {
                            println("The request has been cancelled")
                        }

                    })
```

It will finish with success and token. Log request

Headers

```
{authorization=Basic VGVzdENsaWVudElkOlRlc3RDbGllbnRTZWNyZXQ=, content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded}
```

Body

```
username=%2B79251234567&password=123&grant_type=password
```

---

**OkHttp** is also ok

```
            val client = OkHttpClient()

            val mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            val body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "username=%2B79251234567&password=123&grant_type=password")
            val request1 = Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://192.168.1.28:8888/oauth/token")
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic VGVzdENsaWVudElkOlRlc3RDbGllbnRTZWNyZXQ=")
                    .build()

            val response1 = client.newCall(request1).execute()
            println(response1.message())
```

Comment: Can you show the http post request that unirest is sending ?

Comment: Added headers and body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@POST("oauth/token/")
```

->

```
@POST("oauth/token")
```

The slash (**/**) at the **end** of the line was excess